# name resolution between different docker hosts

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 10 different host each host has many docker containers, which each few container managed by a docker-compose, containers within the docker-compose can communicate with each other, even containers with in the host can communicate with each other although they are from different docker-compose, but now I want to have ability to reach container which is hosted in different machine within the docker host, other than DNS is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

docker-compose is supposed to work only within one host.
If you want your docker containers run on different hosts you should consider using Kubernetes or Docker swarm.

Comment: what about service discovery and network overlay ? can it be considered as an option?

Comment: Yes you can use service discovery for webservice resolution. But then your client side should make request to discoverer to request webservice address.